# For 2019 returns, how are long term gains discounted, if schedule D line 16 amount is entered directly onto line 6 of 1040?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, capital-gains-tax

for 2019 returns, if schedule D line 16 amount is required to be entered onto line 6 of 1040 -- taxed as ordinary income -- how is long term capital gain distribution able to receive favorable tax treatment?

Comment: Line 6 of 1040 is used in calculating your AGI - Adjusted Gross Income, and not the _tax_ due on the income. The tax computation occurs on the Qualified Dividends and Capital Gains Tax Worksheet where the Qualified Dividends and Capital Gains are separated from the AGI and taxed at their appropriate rates while the rest of the AGI is taxed as ordinary income etc. Most tax-preparation software will fill out the QG&CGT worksheet for you without you needing to ask the program to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

In the [instructions for Form 1040, line 12a (tax)](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#idm139798487773184):

> **Qualified Dividends and Capital Gain Tax Worksheet.** Use the Qualified Dividends and Capital Gain Tax Worksheet, later, to figure your tax if you don’t have to use the Schedule D Tax Worksheet and if any of the following applies.
>
> - You reported qualified dividends on Form 1040 or 1040-SR, line 3a.
> - You don’t have to file Schedule D and you reported capital gain distributions on Form 1040 or 1040-SR, line 6.
> - You are filing Schedule D and Schedule D, lines 15 and 16, are both more than zero.

So regardless of whether you file Schedule D or just enter the amount on line 6 of your 1040, you will use a worksheet which provides the more favorable rates for long-term capital gains.